# Проверка скорости работы диска (SSD или нет?)

Tags: linux, ssd

Как понять, ssd у меня диск или нет?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65602/415563

Comment: Проще всего по track-to-track seek. SSD не эмулирует медлительности головок обычного накопителя.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На мой взгляд, самый простой и, в то же время, самый надёжный способ определения типа дисков - прочитать оглавление */dev/disk/by-id*. На моём компе оно выглядит вот так:

```
ata-Samsung_SSD_860_EVO_250GB_S3Y9NX0NB05112E        wwn-0x5000c5003251db33
ata-Samsung_SSD_860_EVO_250GB_S3Y9NX0NB05112E-part1  wwn-0x5000c5003251db33-part1
ata-Samsung_SSD_860_EVO_250GB_S3Y9NX0NB05112E-part2  wwn-0x5000c5003251db33-part2
ata-Samsung_SSD_860_EVO_250GB_S3Y9NX0NB05112E-part3  wwn-0x5000c5003251db33-part3
ata-Samsung_SSD_860_EVO_250GB_S3Y9NX0NB05112E-part4  wwn-0x5000c5003251db33-part4
ata-Samsung_SSD_860_EVO_250GB_S3Y9NX0NB05112E-part5  wwn-0x50014ee2b846f850
ata-ST31000528AS_5VP7E7K6                wwn-0x50014ee2b846f850-part1
ata-ST31000528AS_5VP7E7K6-part1              wwn-0x50014ee2b846f850-part2
ata-ST31000528AS_5VP7E7K6-part2              wwn-0x5002538e90b71d85
ata-ST31000528AS_5VP7E7K6-part3              wwn-0x5002538e90b71d85-part1
ata-ST31000528AS_5VP7E7K6-part4              wwn-0x5002538e90b71d85-part2
ata-WDC_WD10EZRZ-00HTKB0_WD-WCC4J3UDCA5R         wwn-0x5002538e90b71d85-part3
ata-WDC_WD10EZRZ-00HTKB0_WD-WCC4J3UDCA5R-part1       wwn-0x5002538e90b71d85-part4
ata-WDC_WD10EZRZ-00HTKB0_WD-WCC4J3UDCA5R-part2       wwn-0x5002538e90b71d85-part5
```

Если убрать *part* и *wwn*, то останутся три строки:

```
ata-Samsung_SSD_860_EVO_250GB_S3Y9NX0NB05112E
ata-ST31000528AS_5VP7E7K6
ata-WDC_WD10EZRZ-00HTKB0_WD-WCC4J3UDCA5R
```

довольно очевидно, что SSD - это Samsung_SSD_860_EVO_250GB.

Думаю, что не так уж сложно будет найти в иНете полный список винтов всех марок. Не больше нескольких тысяч записей будет. И сделать из них табличку на SQLite.

Answer (score 1):

Можно проверить скорость чтения/записи на диск следующей командой в `linux`:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/root/testfile bs=1G count=1 oflag=direct
```

В случае, если у Вас `ssd`, тогда скорость вряд ли будет ниже 200M. Если у Вас НЕ `ssd`, то она будет существенно ниже, порядка `50M/s`. Пример вывода (НЕ `ssd`):

```
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1,1 GB, 1,0 GiB) copied, 28,3923 s, 37,8 MB/s
```

`ssd`:

```
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB, 1.0 GiB) copied, 2.35849 s, 455 MB/s
```

Comment: ssd может дохнуть... а ещё бывают рейды... Так что способ так себе

Answer (score 1):

Можно ориентироваться на параметр ROTATIONAL RW.
Для этого получаем список дисков, к примеру так:

```bash
lsblk -nb -D --output NAME,TYPE | awk '/disk/{print $1}'
```

И передаем на обработку в цикл

```bash
#!/bin/bash

while read device; do
# Получаем значение по типу устройства
    RW=`cat /sys/block/${device}/queue/rotational`
#Если позиционирующего устройства нет, тогда ssd, иначе hdd
    if [[ ${RW} -eq 0 ]]; then
        type=ssd
    else
        type=hdd
    fi
#Добавляем каждый диск к массиву
    result+=( "$device-$devtype;" )
done< <(lsblk -nb -D --output NAME,TYPE | awk '/disk/{print $1}')
```

После чего можно посмотреть результат

```
echo "${result[@]}"
```

К примеру на одном из серверов вернулся результат:

> sda-ssd;sdb-hdd;

Comment: с тем же результатом и короче: `$ for i in /sys/block/sd*; do cat $i/queue/rotational | sed "s/0/ssd/;s/1/hdd/;s/^/$(basename $i)-/"; done | xargs echo`

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, в таком случае можно и без цикла обойти `grep -H [01] /sys/block/sd*/queue/rotational | sed -r 's/1/hdd/;s/0/ssd/;s/:/-/g;s/\/([a-z]+\/){2}([a-z]+)(\/[a-z]+)+/\2/;s/$/;/'` и без regexp обойтись можно, данные адреса статичны, но в ответе пытался не готовый код предоставить, а саму концепцию получения данных.